# Fixed-length string column in Code First Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm creating an Entity Framework 6 model using Code First Migrations, and I want a column in the resulting database to be fixed-length instead of variable-length; furthermore, I want to do this in a DBMS-agnostic way.

The [ConventionPrimitivePropertyConfiguration.IsFixedLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.conventionprimitivepropertyconfiguration.isfixedlength(v=vs.113).aspx) method seemed built for this purpose. I couldn't find an existing attribute that used it, so I made one myself, like so:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

class FixedLengthAttribute : Attribute { }

class FixedLengthAttributeConvention
    : PrimitivePropertyAttributeConfigurationConvention<FixedLengthAttribute>
{
    public override void Apply(ConventionPrimitivePropertyConfiguration configuration,
        FixedLengthAttribute attribute)
    {
        configuration.IsFixedLength();
    }
}

class MyModel : DbContext
{
    internal virtual DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FixedLengthAttributeConvention());
    }
}

class MyEntity
{
    [Key, FixedLength, StringLength(10)]
    public string MyStringProperty { get; set; }
}
```

However, when running `Add-Migration` using this code, the line that defines that database column in the resulting migration file (`MyStringProperty = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 10)`) doesn't say anything about fixed length. And when I run this migration on a database I get an NVARCHAR column.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `StringLength` attribute appears to be overwritting the `FixedLength` attribute. A workaround is to add the length property to your `FixedLength` attribute and set the `HasMaxLength` yourself

```
class FixedLengthAttribute : Attribute 
{ 
    public int Length { get; set; }
}


public override void Apply(ConventionPrimitivePropertyConfiguration configuration,
        FixedLengthAttribute attribute)
{
    configuration.IsFixedLength();
    configuration.HasMaxLength(attribute.Length);
}

class MyEntity
{
    [Key, FixedLength(Length=10)]
    public string MyStringProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An to alternative to [Aducci's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/469533/aducci) is to use the `ColumnAttribute` to specify the datatype for the column:

```
class MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    [Column(TypeName = "nchar")]
    public string MyEntityId { get; set; }
}
```

This leads to column in the table:

```
MyEntityId nchar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

Personally, I believe this method preferable, as it does not require overriding the `DbContext`'s `Apply` function.